# Как проверить, является ли строка URL в Golang?

Tags: golang

Надо, чтобы условие работало не только с полностью валидными (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), но и по типу stackoverflow.com

Comment: Вы бы пояснили, что означает "работал". Откуда он получает строки - извлекает из сплошного текста, берёт из атрибутов `href` элементов `a`, запросов пользователей? Можно ли как-то определить заранее, какие строки нужно обрабатывать как ссылки?
Без такой подсказки любое слово в тексте можно рассматривать как имя сайта. Нужно уточнить постановку вашей задачи.

Comment: @PakUula в том случае ссылки должен был вводить пользователь в консоль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пакет https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/

```
import "net/url"

u, err := url.ParseRequestURI("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/")
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Он тут без https:// не пустит

Comment: никто не мешает добавить ещё одну проверку, что в начале строки отсутствует http:// и добавить перед проверкой

Answer (score 0):

если вдруг важно, чтобы и все аттрибуты URL были, то я бы предложил такой вариант

```
func isUrl(str string) (bool, error) {
    parsedUrl, err := url.Parse(str)
    return err == nil && parsedUrl.Scheme != "" && parsedUrl.Host != "", err
}
```